# Navigation2] How to make the robot moving backward to the target without turning backwards

Tags: ros-humble

As the title describes, I want my robot to move backward to the target without turning backwards.

What I've done to solve this problem:

1. I set the minimum velocity to minus, according to the advice from [this link.](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103484/nav2-how-to-make-robot-goes-backward).
2. Also, I set the yaw_goal_orientation to 2pi following the same link.

However, I still suffer from the angle tightening issue. I want the robot to move backward while looking straight ahead without shaking. If the yaw goal tolerance is set to 0, the robot turns around toward the target located right behind it and moves forward. On the other hand, if set to 2pi, the robot stumbles but eventually turns around toward the target. Both cases make the robot turn around to the target location, unlike what I wanted.

I now know that I need to handle the custom controller & goal checker plugin, but before start, I'd like to get some hints about which parts are related to the issues I suffer from.

3. I also have erased the controller plugin, in specific I erased the RotateToGoal, GoalAlign, PathAlign plugins.

```
DWB parameters
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
      debug_trajectory_details: True
      min_vel_x: 0.0
      min_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_x: 0.5
      max_vel_y: 0.0
      max_vel_theta: 1.0
      min_speed_xy: 0.0
      max_speed_xy: 0.5
      min_speed_theta: 0.0
      acc_lim_x: 2.5
      acc_lim_y: 0.0
      acc_lim_theta: 3.2
      decel_lim_x: -2.5
      decel_lim_y: 0.0
      decel_lim_theta: -3.2
      vx_samples: 20
      vy_samples: 5
      vtheta_samples: 20
      sim_time: 1.7
      linear_granularity: 0.05
      angular_granularity: 0.025
      transform_tolerance: 0.2
      xy_goal_tolerance: 5.0
      trans_stopped_velocity: 0.25
      short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True
      stateful: True
      critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]
      BaseObstacle.scale: 0.02
      PathAlign.scale: 32.0
      PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      GoalAlign.scale: 24.0
      GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.1
      PathDist.scale: 32.0
      GoalDist.scale: 24.0
      RotateToGoal.scale: 32.0
      RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
      RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0
```

In short, I want to make my robot moves backward toward the target goal without turning backwards and I don't want it to turn around even it arrives at the goal. Which part should I change?
Thanks for reading this article!

Comment: `while facing the front` ... isn't the robot always facing front?

Comment: @jsotola Thank you for pointing it out! I changed the phrase from `while facing the front` to `without turning backwards`

Comment: you have to start thinking about the robot orientation relative to its surroundings, not relative to itself ... `move to the goal while facing away from the goal at all times`